# Why generating function of Bernoulli Numbers is not continuous?

Tags: generating-functions, closed-form, bernoulli-numbers

When deriving the exponential generating function of Bernoulli Numbers and its closed form, I've stumbled upon a huge, to my rigorous heart, problem - discontinuity of the closed form.

$$
 B(t) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} {B_n \frac{t^n}{n!}} = \frac{t}{e^t - 1}
$$

In fact, the closed form has the singularity at $t = 0$. Doesn't it ruin the concept of generating functions?

As far as I know, a closed form of a gf is required to be analytic as a function. It is mainly because we need it to reproduce the encoded sequence by the formula:
$$
B_n = B^{(n)}(0)
$$

In our case, we cannot evaluate directly even $B_0$, as we have a zero denominator.

However, the singularity is removable. And if we put the closed form at $t = 0$ to be $1$, then it becomes analytic!

$$
\text{if $t = 0$ then } B(t) = 1
$$
$$
\text{otherwise }        B(t) = \frac{t}{e^t - 1}
$$

Is it reasonable to use closed form defined in such a way? Or am I mistaken somewhere?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: Often when you divide analytic functions, you get removable singularities, like here. Another example is $\frac{\sin x}x.$

Comment: It's a removable singularity though.  If you additionally define $B(0)=1$ then $B$ is analytic at 0.

Comment: In any event, when you see a generating function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ which is undefined at $0$ in the closed form, the generating function has a removable singularity.

Comment: By the expression $t/(e^t-1)$ they really mean a function $f$ such that
$$f(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{t}{e^t-1}&t\neq 0\\ 1 & t=0\end{cases}$$
But this is very cumbersome, that is, the increased writing does not provide much additional useful information.